# org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I'm using Spring Boot 3 with WebFlux.

Here is my `RouterFunction` configuration :

```
@Autowired
ProductServiceImpl productservice;

@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> router() {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.POST("/addProduct").or(RequestPredicates.PUT("/updateProduct")), productservice::saveOrUpdateProduct)
                              .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/getProduct/{productid}"), productservice::findProductById)
                              .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/getProducts"), productservice::findAllProducts)
                              .andRoute(RequestPredicates.DELETE("/removeProduct/{productid}"), productservice::deleteById)
                              .andRoute(RequestPredicates.DELETE("/removeProducts"), productservice::deleteAll);
    }
```

And here is my Service implementation :

```
@RegisterReflectionForBinding(value = ProductModel.class)
public Mono<ServerResponse> findProductById(ServerRequest request) { 
    return prodrepo.findById(Integer.parseInt(request.pathVariable("productid")))
                   .flatMap(body -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(body))
                   .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build()); 
}
```

Application is running successfully, but when i hit postman with `http://localhost:8081/getProduct/8` using `GET` method, following error is showing on console :

```
    org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:440) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.flatMap(Mono.java:3116)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.handle(AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java:304)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.handle(AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java:304)
    *__Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:85)
    |_     Mono.doOnError ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:84)
    |_ Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:85)
    |_   Mono.doOnSuccess ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:298)
    *__________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ResponseStatusExceptionHandler.handle(ResponseStatusExceptionHandler.java:68)
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:440) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.writeWithMessageWriters(BodyInserters.java:430) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$fromValue$1(BodyInserters.java:103) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$BodyInserterResponse.writeToInternal(DefaultServerResponseBuilder.java:405) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerResponseBuilder$AbstractServerResponse.writeTo(DefaultServerResponseBuilder.java:349) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.write(AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java:351) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.lambda$handle$2(AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.java:304) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen$MonoUsingWhenSubscriber.deferredComplete(MonoUsingWhen.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$CommitInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:528) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:385) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2231) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:246) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:176) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorPublisher.lambda$first$0(BatchCursorPublisher.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:176) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursor.lambda$next$1(BatchCursor.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.next(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:178) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursor.lambda$next$2(BatchCursor.java:42) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4512) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4578) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4339) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorPublisher.lambda$first$1(BatchCursorPublisher.java:119) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:176) ~[reactor-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$sinkToCallback$33(MongoOperationPublisher.java:525) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.OperationExecutorImpl.lambda$execute$2(OperationExecutorImpl.java:94) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:97) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier$RetryingCallback.onResult(RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier.java:116) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:97) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:97) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$exceptionTransformingCallback$6(FindOperation.java:369) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncOperationHelper.lambda$transformingReadCallback$19(AsyncOperationHelper.java:442) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.lambda$executeAsync$0(DefaultServer.java:249) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.lambda$executeAsync$0(CommandProtocolImpl.java:88) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.lambda$sendAndReceiveAsync$1(DefaultConnectionPool.java:802) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.lambda$sendAndReceiveAsync$1(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:155) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:47) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.lambda$sendCommandMessageAsync$0(InternalStreamConnection.java:555) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:849) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:812) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:671) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:668) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:332) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.handleReadResponse(NettyStream.java:359) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.access$1100(NettyStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:435) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:432) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.101.Final.jar:4.1.101.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.